# Android gapless audio looping for files > 1mb

Tags: java, android, loops, audio, android-ndk

I have lately been messing around with the Android audio api and it's starting to annoy me a lot. It basically tried to loop audio files.

I tried many approaches, went through all the possibilities (`SoundPool, MediaPlayer, AudioTrack`), but none of them could guarantee me a click-free looping (It was sometimes good with `setNextMediaPlayer`, but I want to support down to API 13, so it's not an option).

Now I'm about to look deeper into NDK and OpenSL, but I want to be sure I didn't miss something.

Has anybody found any way to gaplessly loop an audiofile? If yes, how did you achieve this? Do I really need to look into NDK and OpenSL? 
If you could give me some examples or ideas I would greatly appreciate that.

I hope you all have a wonderfull day and thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but you could upload it to YouTube, then listen to it on YouTubeRepeat, by just adding "repeat" after the word "youtube" in the URL. It will play forever.

Comment: is it long? can you use PCM data?

Comment: @mbomb007 The YouTube idea sounds interesting, but as you said I want to be able to play it offline also.

Comment: @pskink sadly yes. My files in PCM will be mostly at about 5 to 10mb - Thats why i decided to use Ogg to save some space

Comment: With pcm you can get gapeless audio for sure using AudioTrack, with ogg i dont know...

Comment: True, I tried that, but probably I had a problem with my implementation. It didnt output  any audio and also no error. After 1h of searching I decided to move on ;)

Comment: AudioTrack should work, but are you sure that your files start and end with digital silence?   If not you may need to do your own fade out/fade in.

Comment: try this (you need to adopt it to your needs): http://pastebin.com/njXRgcS1

Comment: Would this article help? http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I exported all files well prepared with cubase.

Comment: @pskink That looks like a nice approach I will definitely try it and let you know my results. I'm currently thinking about a combination of setNextMediaPlayer for >API16 and AudioTrack for <API16. (I could play ogg files on newer devices which would save some space and memory.)

Comment: @mbomb007 i know this application I already used it once, but the seams were a bit too rough - in my opinion - so I make it by hand. Anyways thanks for this tip!